# Is it possible to trace http traffic generated by MSMQ over HTTP with Fiddler?

Tags: msmq, fiddler

I send MSMQ messages over the HTTP transport. The message arrive fine, but I wish to see the actual HTTP traffic. Surele, WireShark shows it. However, Fiddler - does not.

Is it possible to make Fiddler trace the HTTP traffic produced by the MSMQ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answer. Below is the reg script to activate the Fiddler proxy. BTW, using `netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:8888` did not make any difference. I had to run proxycfg on a windows 2003 machine, export the registry and then import it back on my windows 7 station. Only then did Fiddler succeed to trace the MSMQ http traffic.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections]
"WinHttpSettings"=hex:18,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,0e,00,00,00,31,32,37,2e,30,2e,30,2e,31,3a,38,38,38,38,00,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fiddler works as a proxy. So you should make msmq use the proxy port of fiddler. look [at this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/12/17/msmq-messages-using-http-just-won-t-get-delivered-16.aspx) for a pointer.

Comment: Thanks, after a little work following your hint I have finally managed it - I described the process in the body of the question.